# The opposite of "all life"

Tags: word-request

> "If there'll be no oxygen and hydrogen on our planet then only 
>   ______ will remain. All life shall perish!"

By *"all life"* - I mean all organic existence.

But what is the opposite? Everything non-organic, everything made out of plastic, metal, glass?

Comment: Since to perish means "to pass from physical life and lose all bodily attributes and functions necessary to sustain life", I don't think that life and perish is a proper collocation

Comment: By the way, "If there'll be" is not idiomatic: in English we use the simple present in a condition for future meaning: "If there is" - we rely on the "will" in the main clause to convey the future meaning. Alternatively this could be a counterfactual conditional "If there were no oxygen ... would remain".

Comment: @Rompey: I can't see anything wrong with "life" and "perish". "All life" is a common way of saying "All living things".

Comment: @ColinFine I'm not trying to be very idiomatic here but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Rompey That's why I said that by "all life" I mean only all organic existence on the planet but not "inorganic life"

Comment: @SovereignSun: really? Perhaps you are interpreting my "idiomatic" as "colloquial". It can mean that, but particularly in the negative, "not idiomatic" usually means  "something that a native speaker would not say".

Comment: @ColinFine Then I have misunderstood you.

Comment: @SovereignSun- Okay, okay, I only shared my opinion having said: "I don't think that.." And of course, a life may mean a living person and life - living things collectively. Being a non-native English speaker too, I can't but agree with Colin Fine. Yet, I wouldn't use collocations I'm not sure about, being a foreigner to the English-speaking world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that "inorganic material" is the term you are looking for.

> being or composed of matter other than plant or animal
>
> forming or belonging to the inanimate world

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inorganic

Comment: Will it mean all kinds of materials + robots and structures (buildings and e.t.c)?

Comment: And it's an adjective, whilst I need a noun. Material here implies only matter, doesn't it?

Comment: No, "material" is a noun as well as an adjective (and nowadays it's much more common as a noun than an adjective). But I would say "inorganic matter" rather than "inorganic material". I don't think there's a single word for it.

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily be one-word.